# Multiple images in single slideshow item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create [this type of slideshow](http://isellwny.com/).

At first, all the images in a slideshow reveals one by one and after that, it switches to next slideshow.

I need the next and previous functionality too. Can anyone please refer me some jQuery plugins or attach the solutions.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the link says they are using [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). The cycle plugin supports previous and next functionality as well

Here is the review of other jQuery slideshow plugins @ http://www.vandelaydesign.com/jquery-slideshow/